# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array - JSON

Tags: php

I'm working with .json files and I have the following function:

```
//Rights array (WRITE, CREATE, DELETE, ADDUSERS, DELETE USERS)
function addUser($requester, $username, $rights) {
    $file = $requester->getFolder() . "Projects/" . $this->name . "/Data/users.json";
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file, false));
    $json[$username] = array("write" => $rights[0], "create" => $rights[1], "delete" => $rights[2], "adduser" => $rights[3], "deleteuser" => $rights[4]);
    file_put_contents($file, json_encode($json));
}
```

Whenever I run the code that uses that function, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in...

Comment: It would be nice to show us the whole error with content of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of **[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)** defaults to **false**, meaning it will produce an object.  Use **true** to produce an array.

The error comes from `$json[$username]` where you are accessing **$json** as an array.  When it is an object, you would access it like: `$json->$username`.

Comment: I thought it was the other way around... I should've checked :P Thanks man!

Comment: I'm still getting the error. I kept everything the same except: '$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($file, true));' And the error is on this line (39): '$json[$username] = array("write" => $rights[0], "create" => $rights[1], "delete" => $rights[2], "adduser" => $rights[3], "deleteuser" => $rights[4]);'

Comment: Youre using __true__ on file_get_contents, not json_decode.

Comment: Now I've got two errors after I updated with that code: 'Warning: Illegal string offset 'adad' in D:\xampp\htdocs\Collabs\Examples\Project\Scripts\Classes\Project.php on line 39'     ------

'Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\xampp\htdocs\Collabs\Examples\Project\Scripts\Classes\Project.php on line 39'

Comment: Search for those error messages, look into your line number, and try to figure out what the error message is telling you.  You'll eventually need to figure out how to resolve debugging on your own.

Comment: I'll give you a hint.  One of the items you're accessing as an array is a string and one of the items you're accessing as a string is an array.  Using `var_dump()` can help you debug further.

Comment: Found out the problem. Thank you for making me figure it out! The var_dump() function helped. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  You're welcome.